# iPhone Target Linking Error

Tags: iphone, linker, target

So I'm getting this error on build:

[alt text http://grab.by/1lw1](http://grab.by/1lw1)

This obviously has something to do with linking, but I just can't get what exactly. I have 2 targets, and I only get this error when I compile for the device target (other target is for simulator use). I compared the linking settings for each target and everything seems fine.

InfoView is the last class I added to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you're getting that error, you most likely just forgot to include that file in the target. Get info on the file that's giving the error (in this case `InfoView.m`) > targets > check the appropriate targets.

[alt text http://grab.by/1lwF](http://grab.by/1lwF)